# how to use value of a query in a calculated field of a table

Tags: ms-access

In access 2013 I have a table and a query that for example give me sum of one column in that table,
Now I want to use that sum to put it in a calculated field of another column.

is there anyway to do such thing or should I search for something else?

this is my `database`:

[image]

and this is my query:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

I want a Calculated field in `FeedLibrary table` that I can use value of Discount (which is in my query) in it.

Comment: I think you have to provide more details and illustrations. In any case, you can use the `=Dlookup("FieldtoShow","QueryName","Criteria")`.

Comment: @winghei question edited

Comment: Unfortunately you can't create calculated field from fields on another table or query: check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3?CorrelationId=ee71e11e-fa74-47d9-88d5-853d3aebb61c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA101820564

Comment: You can however create another query that has all the fields you want and the calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- If you don't have a `primary key` (unique identifier) in the `FeedLibrary` table, create one.
- Create a second query: `Calc` as the following.

`Calc`:

- Add the `primary key` to the `SelectedFeeds` query.
- Add `FeedLibrary` table and `SelectedFeeds` query.
- Create a relationship by connecting the `primary key` from both the table and the query.
- Add the calculated column.